# What does the phrase “the price of pauses” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, interpretation

I came across this sentence:

> Accepting questions and listening. Letting others reply, even at **the price of pauses**, but persevering until those agree with your perspective.

What does **the price of pauses** actually mean?

Comment: Where did you find that sentence? That might help us decipher it. As for asking for clarification about a duplicate question, the place to ask about that is in our [meta section](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions), but I don't see any closed questions under your account.

Comment: @J.R.: As I haven't registered my account then I lost it (means I can't go back to my original question)

Comment: Yes, that's a problem; you keep creating new accounts and asking new questions. We can sort all that out later. For now, I'll delete that old question that got marked as a duplicate, since you've re-asked it here. But you should still tell us where you found that sentence.

Comment: Use of **price of pauses** does't make sense to me in this context. I can't see what **price** there is to **waiting** in a question and answer scenerio. What is the **urgency**?  Please post more context as per @JR

Comment: Also, you may want to read our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) discussion on meta, which gives tips on asking questions. As for why this was marked as a duplicate, someone thought you this was about the meaning of "at the price of", or "at the cost of", which is addressed in that other question. Perhaps you are more confused by the "pauses" part of this, but, because this is so brief, it's easy to be confused about which part of this short phrase you're struggling with. I hope that helps. But please don't create new accounts each time you ask a new question.

Comment: It's a guidance in a discussion.

Comment: @J.R. Could i post on meta when i only have low reputation?

Comment: "Those" (they?) strikes me an unidiomatic here. Non-native-speaking author?  "Even at the price of pauses" could be an attempt at something like "even at the risk of delays".

Comment: @made - There's no need to address this issue in meta now that this question is open. I was just letting you know what to do the next time you encounter a closed-as-duplicate ruling that you don't agree with.

Answer (score 4):

This implies pauses <sub>(in a conversation? discussion? That's why J.R. is asking for more context)</sub> are, in principle, undesirable and should normally be avoided. The writer describes a goal which can only be obtained by allowing those pauses.

Another common phrase for this is '[at the expense of](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-the-expense-of)'.